# Make efficient query with django

Tags: django, performance, django-queryset

Let's define these models:

```
class Family(models.Model):
     .....

class Person(models.Model):
     family = models.ForeignKey(Family)
     .....
```

Let's say we have *family_object* which is any Family instance so we can find people of this family in two ways:

```
a) Person.objects.filter(family=family_object)
b) Person.objects.filter(family__id=family_object.id)
```

which one is more efficient? there is any rule for this case?

Comment: This question has not shown any effort to profile "a" and "b"; Do that and you will answer your own question. I guess there is no significant difference.

Comment: you can print the query generated by appending `.query` at the end. Behind the scenes, `__` translates to a join. Since you already have the object, you could even do `.filter(family_id=family_object.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some testing reveals they generate the same db queries:

```
q1 = str(Person.objects.filter(family=family_object).query)
q2 = str(Person.objects.filter(family__id=family_object.id).query)
q3 = str(Person.objects.filter(family_id=family_object.id).query)

q1 == q2 == q3
```

The overhead of pulling ids from django objects through the ORM should be terribly minor.

I'm actually a little surprised.. I figured `__` would be a join, and `family=family_object` would have no join. Both produce no joins with django 1.6.

Django knows the `__id` lookup is on the PK and skips the join. Cool.

Comment: Anyway I think `q1` should be the "standard", shouldn't it? I mean use it instead `q2/q3` if possible

Comment: `q1` or `q3` is intuitive to me.